# How can I save a PictureBox graphics object to a Stream?

Tags: c#, graphics, stream

I have a PictureBox control that has got a graphics object attached for drawing; whenever the tick event of a Timer triggers I should save the current PictureBox graphics on a Stream, clear the PictureBox image and restore the graphics object that I saved before as an Image.

How can I do that?

Comment: You would have to be drawing into an image, then just save the image.

Comment: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface... You can use [DrawToBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to save the things you have drawn into a Bitmap. Make sure that you only ever draw in the Paint event using the e.Graphics object or else it can't be saved. Never use control.CreateGraphics !

Comment: Do you mean something like this: MemoryStream stream=new MemoryStream(); 
pictureBox1.Image.Save(stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);